# Getting NSDictionary key by index?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsdictionary, uipickerview

Is it possible to get a dictionary key by index?

I'm trying to use a dictionary for the datasource of a picker view and want to access it in following delegate method:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
if (component == 0){
   return  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[myDict // how to get the key]];
}
```

EDIT--

myDict is something like:

Item 1

- sub item 1
- sub item 2

Item 2

- sub item 1
- sub item 2

I want to use myDict as the datasource for a picker view that has 2 sections:

section 0 = myDict keys (Item 1, Item 2)

section 1 = corresponding myDict values for selected section 0 row (sub item 1, sub item 2)

Comment: What do you mean by getting dictionary key by index? How about elaborate it more by showing example or more code?

Comment: Dictionaries don't have an index, you can use the allKeys method to get an array of the keys.

Comment: Read the NSDictionary spec and see what functions are available.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since `NSDictionary` is an *unordered* associative container, it has no concept of indexing. Its keys are ordered arbitrarily, and that order can change in the future.

You can get an `NSArray` of keys from the dictionary, and apply indexing to it:

```
NSArray *keys = [myDict allKeys]; // Warning: this order may change.
```

However, this indexing scheme would remain consistent only as long as the dictionary remains unchanged: for example, if you use `NSMutableDictionary`, adding an extra key may change the ordering of the existing keys. This leads to extremely hard-to-debug problems.

A better approach would be to place the items for your picker into an ordered container, such as `NSArray`. Create a special class for the picker items, for example

```
@interface MyPickerItem : NSObject
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) NSString *item1;
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) NSString *item2;
@end
```

create an `NSArray` of such `MyPickerItem` objects from your dictionary, order them the way you want them to appear in the picker view (say, alphabetically by `item1`, then by `item2`) and use `NSArray` as the data source for your picker view:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    MyPickerItem *p = myArray[row];
    switch (component) {
        case 0: return p.item1;
        case 1: return p.item2;
    }
    return @"<-ERROR->";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This will give you randomly ordered keys

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row    forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    if (component == 0){
        return  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[myDict allKeys][row]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, as a dictionary doesn't have order.

You'll need to provide an array of keys, which will give you your order, in addition to the dictionary.

```
@interface MyClass ()
@property NSMutableArray *keysArray;     // Don't forget to allocate this in an init method
@end

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
             titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
            forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (component == 0){
        NSString *key = self.keysArray[row];
        return self.myDict[key];    // I assume you just want to return the value
    }
    ...
```

Comment: +1 for the reminder about allocating the `NSMutableDictionary`. the number of times I have driven myself crazy because I forgot to do that…

Answer (score 1):

`NSDictionary` is an unordered data structure which means that accessing with an index doesn't make much sense. You probably want an `NSArray` instead. However, if your dictionary is using `NSNumbers` as keys then you would access it like this.

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    if (component == 0) {
       return  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myDict[@(row)]];
    }
}
```